# God murugan is considered as tamil god. Is he known to all hindus?

Tags: shiva, kartikeya

God Murugan is known as lord Shiva's son and also called as [Kartikeya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya). He used to be called as Tamil god and famous in Tamil Hindus. Is he known to all Hindus?

Comment: Are you kidding? He is Shiva's son and all Hindus worship him but Tamilians worship Him more.

Comment: These are just trends that have evolved over time due to multiple reasons especially political ones